# Discord.js UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

Ok, so I just started working on a discord bot and implemented a command handler, and I immediately ran into some problems.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
module.exports = {
  name: "kick",
  description: "Kicks the mentioned user",
  execute(message, args) {
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();

    if (user) {
      const member = message.guild.member(user);
      try {
        const kickEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setTitle("You were Kicked")
          .setDescription("You were kicked from Bot Testing Server.");
        user.send({ kickEmbed }).then(() => {
          member.kick();
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("failed to kick user");
      }
    }
  }
};
```

when i execute the kick command in my server, I get the following error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
```

I can't seem to find anything wrong with the code so, where's the error

Comment: I know the answer was accepted, but it was not for the correct reason. The reason why this failed was that the `send()` method requires an object definition if you want to send an embed, so if you wanted to send your embed, you would need to do `send({ embed: kickEmbed })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending an embed that uses the Discord Rich Embed builder you don't need to use the curly brackets.
Instead of `user.send({ kickEmbed })` you should do `user.send(kickEmbed)`. I ran into that issue before and it helped in my case.